# How can I style nested elements within slotted elements?

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, lit-element

I'm creating a simple custom element using Lit Element. This element will take various inputs via slots. I'm not even using named slots at this point.

I'm having trouble applying style to an element that is nested within a slotted. For example, in [this snippet](https://codepen.io/aver-mimas/pen/qePZXY) I am consuming 3 different variations of this element like this:

```
<content-card>
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</content-card>

<content-card heading="Card2 title" background="grey">
    <p>Content of Card 2</p>
    <a href="#">Terms of Use</a>
    <p>There's more</p>
</content-card>

<content-card heading="Another card with long title & content" background="dark">
  <p>Content of card3. <a href="#">Policy</a></p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nesciunt cupiditate, nam vel ad sit maxime soluta? Molestias accusamus cupiditate, dolor corrupti id pariatur laudantium velit. Odio temporibus nesciunt officiis!</p>
</content-card>
```

I can't seem to apply the background/color style to the `<a>` element in that last custom element. If it's not nested as in the 2nd `<content-card>`, then it's okay.

What am I missing so that I can apply the same style to the `<a>` element regardless of where it is within the custom element's slot?

Comment: Seams not applying CSS styling, if it is in `<p>` element. When u remove `<p>`, it's working. So, this is a weak side of `LitElement`

Answer (score 1):

`::slotted()` will only apply to top-level elements assigned in a `<slot>`.

Therefore you cannot use it to style a nested element. In your case the `<a>` style will be the one defined in the main document (because `<a>` is in the light DOM so it inherits from the global CSS style).

The solution is then to define the CSS for `<a>` in the main document. You can insert it in the `<head>` element, or at the light DOM level. To limit the specific style to the Custom Element content, add its name before:

```
<style>
    custom-card a {
        color: white;
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

```js
customElements.define( 'custom-card', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeBegin', `<style> custom-card a { color: red } </style>` )
        this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
            .innerHTML = `<div><slot></slot></div>`
    }
} )
```

```html
<custom-card>
  <a href>First level link</a>
  <p><a href>Link inside a paragraph</a></p>
</custom-card>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the example. 2 questions. What is the `this.attachShadow` for inside the `connectedCallback()` function? Looks like I'm able to get the style effect without it. And, this adds a `style` element in the document for every `custom-card` element. Is there a more efficient way to handle this scenario? The purpose of using slots was to encapsulate everything within the custom element and hide implementation details from clients. Is the root of the problem coming from using slots?

Comment: @aver 1. I used attachShadow in the example because I used vanilla JavaScript instead of LitElement (for simplicity and because it is not linked). If you don't use Shadow DOM of course you can get the style effect (and ::slotted() and <slot> would not work anyway). 2. No. Yes the root of the problem comes from sing slots. ::slotted() can target only single elements (not the children)

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification. The only issue I have right now is the duplicated `style` element for each instances of `custom-card` element.

Comment: @aver alternately you could insert the style element only one in the header (from outside of the custum element definition)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Although, I found 2 work arounds:

**Workaround 1 - Use Javascript To Style**

(1) Access the slotted elements from javascript by using @queryAssignedElements (See https://lit.dev/docs/components/shadow-dom/#query-assigned-nodes)

(2) For each slotted element, parse its dom tree and style the child nodes using javascript (e.g. childelement.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0';)

**Workaround 2 - Copy Slotted HTML to Another Div**

(1) Access the slotted elements from javascript by using @queryAssignedElements (See https://lit.dev/docs/components/shadow-dom/#query-assigned-nodes)

(2) For every slotted element under consideration, copy-paste its outerHTML to another empty div, placed next to it.

(3) Since these initially empty divs are not from the slots, you can setup static css rules for them.

(4) Empty the slots after the copy pasting into the adjacent divs is complete.

In short, use the slots as inlets.